# Query data frame using list of columns and list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following simple data frame:

```
stores = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
brands = ['Nike', 'Nike', 'Adidas', 'Nike', 'Adidas']
colours = ['Black', 'Black', 'White', 'Black', 'Black']
data = dict(stores=stores, brands=brands, colours=colours)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.keys())
```

I'd like to query this using a list of columns and a corresponding list of values. For e.g.

```
columns = ['stores', 'brands']
values = ['a', 'Nike']
df[columns == values]
```

**Is this possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible using [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) with [`reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) for an arbitrary number of conditions:

```
import numpy as np

df[np.logical_and.reduce([df[col] == val for col, val in zip(columns, values)])]
```

Results:

```
  stores brands colours
0      a   Nike   Black
1      a   Nike   Black
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a similar way to thesilkworm's answer using only pandas:

```
query = " & ".join([c + " == '" + v + "'" for c,v in zip(columns, values)])
df.query(query)
```

Output using the above code:

```
>>> query = " & ".join([c + " == '" + v + "'" for c,v in zip(columns, values)])
>>> query
"stores == 'a' & brands == 'Nike'"
>>> df.query(query)
  stores brands colours
0      a   Nike   Black
1      a   Nike   Black
```

Note the inclusion of single quotes around `v` in the list comprehension.  These are important, since we're comparing a string value.  For more info, see the [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) documentation for pandas.